# Token not being persisted across Cypress tests

Tags: cookies, cypress

I have created a Cypress command to fetch me a JWT token from my GQL API. I then set the token as a cookie to use in my tests that require authentication.

Here is my login command:

```js
export function login(username, password) {
  const { apiUrl: url } = Cypress.env();
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url,
    body: {
      operationName: 'signin',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      query:
        `mutation signin($email: String!, $password: String!) {
          signin(input: {email: $email, password: $password}) {
            id
            token
            __typename
          }
        }`,
      variables: { email: username, password: password }
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    const { token } = response.body.data.signin;
    cookie.set('token', token, { expires: 10000000 });
    cy.wait(3000);
  });
}
```

I can see when I run the `login` command the cookie is set but when my test tries to visit a page within my app the cookie disappears.

```js
describe('Entity Page', () => {
  before(() => {
    const { username, password } = Cypress.env();
    cy.login(username, password);

    cy.addEntity(newEntityId, {});

    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.get('@entityId').then(entityId => {
      cy.visit(`/entity/${entityId}`)
      cy.wait(6000)
    });
  });
```

By the time I get to `addEntity` the cookie disappears and I am unauthenticated. Is there something I need to do to persist cookies? I tried `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce` but this had no effect

I also tried adding the below to my `support/index.js` but the cookie is still removed.

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: 'token'
})
```

Comment: It's definitely the expiry - with 10 million it disappears, but use 1.7 billion takes you to 2023-11-14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `cy.setCookie(name, value)` [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie#Arguments).

It has a couple of defaults that might help.

- domain - defaults to window.location.hostname. The domain the cookie is visible to.
- expiry - defaults to 20 years into the future. Specified as seconds since 1 January 1970 (10,000,000 is only 115 days).

Comment: I tried `cy.setCookie` and now the `visit` method calls just hang indefinitely & Cypress seems to be taking up 287.4% of my CPU, have you encountered this before?

Comment: No, and setting the cookie wouldn't be doing that. I did a simple setCookie to test the expiry thing and it was fine. But if you're confident about  `cookie.set('token', ...)` use that but the point is you need to bump up that expiry figure.